# A display question about Opencv&ROS

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , I am learning how to use OpenCV in ROS recently , now I meet a question about display the image .
Here is my code :

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("node1");
cv::namedWindow("test",1);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("node2");
```

But after I run the code , there is not window display . The terminal just print these information :

```
[ INFO] [1407293765.605951849]: node1
[ INFO] [1407293765.629249378]: node2
```

I can not understand why . Can you help me ?
Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189081/a-display-question-about-opencv&ros/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-08-05**:
does it show when you add cd::waitKey(0); after cv::namedWindow ?

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-06**:
Yes , It occurs . But why ? I wrote " ros::spin() " at the end of "int main(...) ", does the code running in a loop ?

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-06**:
I ran the code in http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages , it still did not occur the window .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check the code, image_converter.cpp the images are shown in line 53

```
  51     // Update GUI Window
  52     cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
  53     cv::waitKey(3);
```

cv::waitKey handles any windowing events, such as creating windows or showing images.
if you call cv::imshow() in a loop through video frames, without following up each draw with cv::waitKey(3) nothing appears on screen, because highgui is never given time to process the draw requests from cv::imshow(). If you insist on showing an empty window before getting the images add

```
cv::waitKey(3);
```

after

```
cv::namedWindow("test",1);
```

you can replace 3 by any other small number, it expresses how long opencv should wait in milliseconds.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-06**:
Yes , the window occurred . Thank you . Maybe it should wait for several ms after imshow or namedwindow in Linux . I never met this problem in win7 with VS or QtCreator .